# Wait for Download to finish in selenium webdriver JAVA

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Once clicking a download button, files will be downloaded. Before executing next code, it needs to wait until the download completes.

My code looks like this:

```
Thread.sleep(2000);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='perform']")).click();//click for download

Thread.sleep(20000);
//code to be executed after download completes
Readfile fileobj=new Readfile();
String checkfile=fileobj.checkfilename();
```

How can I make the webdriver wait until a download completes?

Comment: How can I make the webdriver to wait until a download complete

Comment: This is stepping beyond the capabilities of WebDriver, once a download starts, it is no longer a browser operation, hence WebDriver cannot control it as such. Check out this blog post which is very informative when it comes to this very topic. http://ardesco.lazerycode.com/index.php/2012/07/how-to-download-files-with-selenium-and-why-you-shouldnt/

Comment: link update: http://ardesco.lazerycode.com/testing/webdriver/2012/07/25/how-to-download-files-with-selenium-and-why-you-shouldnt.html

Comment: Check my answer [below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22714112/wait-for-download-to-finish-in-selenium-webdriver-java/56569251#56569251) which works 100% with the latest chrome browser (python implementation but you can port it to any other languages).

Answer (score 20):

A little late but this question has a good number of views, I thought it would be worth the time to answer it in case you haven't moved on or someone else comes across it.

I too ran into the same problem and thought I'd share. I was developing in python at the time but the same concept applies. You don't have to do the actual download using selenium. Rather than clicking on the element to start the download, you should consider retrieving the link and using built in functions to proceed from there.

The element you would normally click to begin the download should have a 'href' attribute that you should be able to read using selenium. This is the url pointing to the actual file. In python, it looks something like this:

```
    element = driver.find_element_by_id('dl_link')
    url = element.get_attribute('href')
```

From here you can use an http library to call the url. The important part here is that you set 'stream' to true so you can begin writing the bytes to a file. Make sure the file path contains the correct file extension and another thing, most operating systems don't allow you to name files with certain characters such as back slashes or quotations so heads up on that.

```py
def download_file(url, file_path):
    from requests import get
    reply = get(url, stream=True)
    with open(file_path, 'wb') as file:
        for chunk in reply.iter_content(chunk_size=1024): 
            if chunk:
                file.write(chunk)
```

The program shouldn't continue until the download is complete making it no longer necessary to poll until it is complete.

I apologize for answering in a different language, in Java I believe you can use the HttpURLConnection API. Hope this helps!

Comment: This is excellent for when it applies. I deal with plenty of sites that don't use something as simple as putting the file in `href`, but if they do, this is great.

Comment: This is not wrong, I also used this method before. And to make this work with authentication, u can get the cookies from selenium's driver and append to the http request. But, Its a pain when the download link is generated by js. And also you cant test if clicking the download button actually downloads the file. I switched back to the normal thing, click the button and do the `file.exists()` check in a loop. And for selenium in a hub-node architecture, I use `ssh` to `ls` or `dir` the file for existence.

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for this solution. It makes things a lot easier and cleaner to manage. I have a doubt about the `stream` keyword argument though. I ran the code without passing the `stream=True` argument and it seemed to run unchanged. Can you please elaborate on what the purpose of that argument is?

Answer (score 8):

```
do {

   filesize1 = f.length();  // check file size
   Thread.sleep(5000);      // wait for 5 seconds
   filesize2 = f.length();  // check file size again

} while (filesize1 != filesize2);
```

where f is a File, filesize is long

Comment: Won't this condition go into an infinite loop? Cause filesize1 will never be equal to filesize2

Answer (score 8):

I use Scala for my automation but the port to Java should be trivial since I use java Selenium classes there anyway.
So, first you need this:

```scala
import com.google.common.base.Function
import java.nio.file.{Files, Paths, Path}

def waitUntilFileDownloaded(timeOutInMillis:Int)={
    val wait:FluentWait[Path] = new FluentWait(Paths.get(downloadsDir)).withTimeout(timeOutInMillis, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).pollingEvery(200, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
    wait.until(
      new Function[Path, Boolean] {
        override def apply(p:Path):Boolean = Files.list(p).iterator.asScala.size > 0
      }
    )
  }
```

Then in my test suite where I need to download xls file I just have this:

```scala
def exportToExcel(implicit driver: WebDriver) = {
    click on xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'export_csv')]")
    waitUntilFileDownloaded(2000)
  }
```

I hope you've got the idea. FluentWait is very useful abstraction and though it is a part of Selenium it can be used wherever you need to wait with polling till some condition is met.

Answer (score 6):

The below code is working fine for me.

Also no warning will be as I used generic type and `Duration` as recommended.

```
File file = new File("C:\\chromedriver_win32.zip");
FluentWait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver).withTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(25)).pollingEvery(Duration.ofMillis(100));
wait.until( x -> file.exists());
```

Answer (score 5):

I like awaitility

```
    Path filePath = Paths.get(".", "filename");
    await().atMost(1, MINUTES)
            .ignoreExceptions()
            .until(() -> filePath.toFile().exists());
```

More info: http://www.testautomationguru.com/selenium-webdriver-how-to-wait-for-expected-conditions-using-awaitility/

Answer (score 4):

Well, your file is stored somewhere, right? So, check if it exists in file system

```
File f = new File(filePathString);

do {
  Thread.sleep(3000);
} while (f.exists() && f.length() == expectedSizeInBytes)
```

Comment: Surely this will loop infinitely when the file is finished? Shouldn't the logic me more like: while not exists or while less than expected size?

Comment: Yeap, some exit condition must be added. This is just a general advise not exact working solution for one particular case.

Answer (score 3):

A java adaptation of Alexander Arendar's idea :

(using Java 8 & the predicate version of until method of FluentWait)

```
  private void waitForFileDownload(int totalTimeoutInMillis, String expectedFileName) throws IOException {  
            FluentWait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait(this.funcDriver.driver)
                                   .withTimeout(totalTimeoutInMillis, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                                   .pollingEvery(200, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
            File fileToCheck = getDownloadsDirectory()
                               .resolve(expectedFileName)
                               .toFile();

            wait.until((WebDriver wd) -> fileToCheck.exists());

        }


public synchronized Path getDownloadsDirectory(){
        if(downloadsDirectory == null){

            try {
                downloadsDirectory = Files.createTempDirectory("selleniumdownloads_");
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Failed to create temporary downloads directory");
            }
        }
        return downloadsDirectory;
    }
```

Note the use of createTempDirectory to avoid the caveats of recursively deleting more than intended as well as automatically safely disposing of the folder when we re done with it.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using chrome for the download, the you can use the below method to make sure the script will wait until the download is completed.

**Python Implementation:**

```py
def waitUntilDownloadCompleted(maxTime=600):
    driver.execute_script("window.open()")
    # switch to new tab
    driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[-1])
    # navigate to chrome downloads
    driver.get('chrome://downloads')
    # define the endTime
    endTime = time.time() + maxTime
    while True:
        try:
            # get the download percentage
            downloadPercentage = driver.execute_script(
                "return document.querySelector('downloads-manager').shadowRoot.querySelector('#downloadsList downloads-item').shadowRoot.querySelector('#progress').value")
            # check if downloadPercentage is 100 (otherwise the script will keep waiting)
            if downloadPercentage == 100:
                # exit the method once it's completed
                return downloadPercentage
        except:
            pass
        # wait for 1 second before checking the percentage next time
        time.sleep(1)
        # exit method if the download not completed with in MaxTime.
        if time.time() > endTime:
            break
```

Just call the method when ever you click on download link/button.

```py
# click on download button
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='perform']").click()
#wait until the download completed
waitUntilDownloadCompleted(120) #2 minutes
```

Comment: Works - but only if Chrome does not run in headless mode :(

Answer (score 2):

```py
import time
from os import walk

download_dir = 'path\\to\\download\\folder'


def check_if_download_folder_has_unfinished_files():
    for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in walk(download_dir):
        return str(filenames)


def wait_for_files_to_download():
    time.sleep(5)  # let the driver start downloading
    file_list = check_if_download_folder_has_unfinished_files()
    while 'Unconfirmed' in file_list or 'crdownload' in file_list:
        file_list = check_if_download_folder_has_unfinished_files()
        time.sleep(1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    wait_for_files_to_download()
```

Comment: Works great for implementations where you're waiting for multiple files to download all at once! I'm definitely using this. One drawback is if there are aborted unfinished downloads already in your download directory, this won't work.

Comment: @Giselle Serate, thanks for comment. You are right. I generate new "download_dir" for every new download session.

Answer (score 1):

Some operating systems (e.g. Mac OS X) don't set the filename until the download is complete. So it seems sufficient to use a wait or a while loop to check for the file to exist.

e.g.

```
File file = new File(fullPathToFile);
while (!file.exists()) {
    Thread.sleep(1000);
}
```

Comment: This will result in an infinite loop if file is never found. Not a good way!!

Answer (score 1):

This one worked for me:

```
    Path filePath = Paths.get("path/to/file/fileName.pdf");
    File file = filePath.toFile(); 

 void waitForFileDownloaded(File file, int timeoutSeconds) {
        WebDriver driver = getDriver();
        FluentWait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<>(driver)
                .withTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(timeoutSeconds))
                .pollingEvery(Duration.ofMillis(500))
                .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class, StaleElementReferenceException.class);
        wait.until((webDriver) -> file.exists());
    }
```

Comment: Hi Konstantin, please familiarise yourself with [writing answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) before writing your next one. Enjoy your stay at SO :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's one using just WebDriverWait:

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(d -> Paths.get(downloadDir, downloadFileName).toFile().exists());
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will always work.. Try it out guys!

```
public void waitForFileDownloaded(String fileName, int timeoutSeconds) {
    FluentWait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<>(driver)
            .withTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(timeoutSeconds))
            .pollingEvery(Duration.ofMillis(500))
            .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class, StaleElementReferenceException.class);
    wait.until((x) -> {
        File[] files = new File(downloadfolderPath).listFiles();
        for (File file : files) {
            if (file.getName().contains(fileName)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am your the bellow code in Python + Firefox, but it can be adapted to Java:

```py
browser.get('about:downloads')  #Open the download page.
# Wait all icons change from "X" (cancel download)
WebDriverWait(browser, URL_LOAD_TIMEOUT * 40).until_not(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'downloadIconCancel')))
```