# How to open a downloaded excel file in selenium

Tags: selenium, automation

Can anyone please help me with the below issue?

on clicking a download file its gets downloaded successfully but I'm having trouble opening the file.

Can anyone suggest to me how could I open a file that is the download for Mac

Comment: Add the code you've tried.

Comment: Check out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65680591/1387701

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't post any sample code, but anyway, check out this generic example.

```
import requests
url = "https://www.nordpoolgroup.com/Market-data1/Power-system-data/Production1/Wind-Power-Prognosis/DK/Hourly/?view=table"

r = requests.post(url)   #POST Request
with open('data_123.xls', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(r.content)

# file goes here, by default, if WD is not changed to somewhere else:
# C:\Users\your_path_here\
```