# how can I verify a file downloaded from chrome browser running on selenium node system

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, selenium-grid

Want to verify that the file is getting downloaded in actual or not not just success message pop-up validation

I considered using `file.exist()` in my code but that checks locally wher my code is being executed. Also I considered opening default Download location in browser and get page source and do check contains but with that aproach I stuck with getting the node system's username (without it i can define the exact path to open in browser e.g. `C://Users/<username>/Downloads`. Also tried opening `chrome://downloads` in browser but downloading source from there doesn't contain file name :(

is there any in general way to access system files of node system etc.

Comment: Try the answer in below link, if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32046501/7598774

Answer (score 0):

1. Before and after download check file's modified date
2. Another way is to check the file path where the file is getting downloaded.

You can use the os module in Node.js to get the current user's home directory after that append the path to the download location 
(e.g. "Downloads" on Windows and Mac, "~/Downloads" on Linux).

Comment: Actually the problem is, the execution is happening on selenium node system and file gets downloaded there