# Selenium VBA wait for excel to automatically open downloaded csv

Tags: excel, vba, selenium

I have a macro using Selenium that opens chrome, navigates to one of our web applications and downloads a csv file by right clicking and selecting download:

```
Sub reporting_extractor()
Dim bot As New selenium.WebDriver

    bot.SetPreference "download.extensions_to_open", "csv"

    bot.Start "chrome", "http://******************************"
    bot.Get "/"
    bot.Window.Maximize

    bot.FindElementByXPath("//th[contains(text(),'SiteA')]").ClickContext
    bot.FindElementByXPath("//ul[@class='dropdown-menu']/li/a").Click '"download as csv" in context menu

    'wait for file to open

    'perform actions in opened file

End Sub
```

due to "download.extensions_to_open" the csv file automatically opens in excel when downloaded, but the problem is that the code is trying to continue while the file is being downloaded and invariably causes an error.
Unfortunately, the file is created when I click the download button so I cant use `WorkBooks.open("https://********")` that I found in one of the answers for similar questions about opening files from web.

I tried codes like

```
    While Not ActiveWorkbook.name Like "export*"
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
        DoEvents
    Wend
```

with different versions of the code that should stop the execution of the code like `Sleep 1000`, `bot.Wait 1000` from the selenium itself or `Do Until Now > Start + TimeValue("0:00:05")`. Everything with or without DoEvents. Everything resulted in the same thing - the file is downloaded, but there doesnt seem to be any attempt to open it no matter how long I wait.

If I put `Stop` there instead of the wait code the file opens almost immediately, but then I have no way of starting it again with some code. I think I could create a workaround by saving the file to specific location using

```
bot.SetPreference "download.default_directory", myFolder
bot.SetPreference "download.directory_upgrade", True
```

and then get the name of the latest downloaded file from downloads-manager, so I could open it directly after waiting couple of seconds for download to finish, where (I think) the macro would either wait or some of the wait codes would work, but that seems like awfully complicated way to do things.

Am I missing something concerning the wait code? I would very much appreciate any help.

Comment: Here's a question that looked for the same using Selenium in Java/Python.  In your situation, I'd be inclined to explore the approach from spatel4140's answer: read the href from the clickable element, then download the target file using a means that raises an event or otherwise facilitates waiting. 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22714112/wait-for-download-to-finish-in-selenium-webdriver-java

Comment: Do you need the file to be opened? Why not simply download without opening? Then open later?

Comment: @TrevorReid: thank you for suggestion. I will try to see if I can translate this somehow to vba, but I see a possible problem here. Although the element I click is <a> it has no href attribute. The only thing that controls what happens (I guess) is "data-ng-click="menuExportCtrl.exportData(true)"" which I confess have no idea if can be used.

Comment: @QHarr: the first reason was because I wasnt sure I can figure out the shadow-root inside the downloads manager - I download the file multiple times so I cant simply use filename to open it, I could cycle through the folder and find the newest file, but that seemed needlessly complicated. I found code to navigate the shadow-root so that is not a problem,so what remains is curiosity if it can be done that way and the fact that it would be lot shorter to code. I guess by trying to figure things out in more effective way I believe I get better even though sometimes the result is it cant be done.