# Handle Document Download in Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I had a automated tool in `Selenium` using `Chrome Driver` which navigates to a website,search something and downloads the Documnet by clicking on download button

when I clicked the download button it opened in Chrome PDF Viewer, so I had disabled Chrome Driver as

```
 ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
 options.AddArguments("test-type");
 options.AddArguments("disable-popup-blocking");
 options.AddArgument("disable-extensions");
 options.AddUserProfilePreference("plugins.plugins_disabled", new[] {
                "Adobe Flash Player",
                "Chrome PDF Viewer"
            });

options.AddUserProfilePreference("download.default_directory", TempDownloadFolder);



IWebDriver webdriver = new ChromeDriver(ChromeBrowser_exe, options);
```

Now after Clicking the Download button the document is being processed in browser and the download as full document.

I had used Thread.Sleep(180000) - 3 Minutes wait for the document to download and do some other proccess.

Some Documents are being downloded within 1 minutes still its waiting for 3 Minutes as I had set Thread.Sleep(180000).Kindly anyone guide me in Step to handle the document download prcessing in Selenium Chrome Driver

Comment: Have a look at the last answer on this post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21930969/how-to-wait-for-download-to-finish-using-webdriver. Using an infinite loop to poll document state with javascript executor. May work.

Comment: @Grasshopper The solution said by you had worked perfectly, Kindly post it as answer So that I can Accept it

Comment: It is not my answer I just mentioned the link to you. Please upvote the original answer as it worked for you. Thanks.